# Extended Choice Parameter: How to load params dynamically from any file for jenkins build job

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Though below code works fine individually:

```
extendedChoice description: '', multiSelectDelimiter: ',', name: 'Capablities', quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_CHECKBOX',value: 'Chrome_macos10_15, Chrome_win10', visibleItemCount: 30
```

I need Chrome_macos10_15, Chrome_win10 need to be passed from external file.

How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Active Choice Parameter plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) which allows you to run a Groovy script to dynamically load values for your parameters.